# Web service using SOAP, WSDL not working - PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to gain access to a 'free' web service which publishes London Gold and Silver Fixes.

I have found the following two services, but I am unable to get the services to return any useful data.

Am I doing something wrong or is the server not publishing any data?
Does anybody know of any other 'free' London Gold & Silver Fix servers which work?

CLIENT CODE:

```
<pre>
<?php
$c = new soapclient('http://www.restfulwebservices.net/wcf/LondonGoldFixService.svc?wsdl');
print_r($c->GetMarketData());
?>
</pre>
<br />

<pre>
<?php
$c = new soapclient('http://www.webservicex.net/londongoldfix.asmx?wsdl');
print_r($c->GetLondonGoldAndSilverFix());
?>
</pre>
```

SERVER OUTPUT:

```
    stdClass Object
    (
    [GetMarketDataResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Gold_AM_USD] => 0
            [Gold_AM_STG] => 0
            [Gold_AM_EUR] => 0
            [Gold_PM_USD] => 0
            [Gold_PM_STG] => 0
            [Gold_PM_EUR] => 0
            [Silver_CENTS] => 0
            [Silver_PENCE] => 0
            [Silver_EUR] => 0
            [Status] => Failed
        )
)

stdClass Object
(
    [GetLondonGoldAndSilverFixResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Gold_AM_USD] => 0
            [Gold_AM_STG] => 0
            [Gold_AM_EUR] => 0
            [Gold_PM_USD] => 0
            [Gold_PM_STG] => 0
            [Gold_PM_EUR] => 0
            [Silver_CENTS] => 0
            [Silver_PENCE] => 0
            [Silver_EUR] => 0
            [Status] => Failed
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the server is returning data. It's all zero. Your soap code is working. The website must be returning bad data or be broken.